# Why won't my else if statements work?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to create a BART Fare program for my programming class. However no matter the input, my result is always -1. Why won't my program follow the else if statements?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the ticket type: ");
    String type = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the zone number: ");
    int zone = input.nextInt();

    if ((zone <= 2) && (type == "adult")){
        System.out.println("The fare is 20.");
    }   else if ((zone <= 2) && (type == "child")){
        System.out.println("The fare is 10.5.");
    }   else if ((zone == 3) && (type == "adult")){
        System.out.println("The fare is 30.5.");
    }   else if ((zone == 3) && (type == "child")){
        System.out.println("The fare is 20.");
    }   else if ((zone == 4) && (type == "child")){
        System.out.println("The fare is 20.");
    }   else if ((zone == 4) && (type == "adult")){
        System.out.println("The fare is 43.");
    }   else if ((zone > 4) || (type != "adult") || (type != "child"))
        System.out.println("-1");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your last `else if` is missing an "`{`"

Your other problem is the way you are comparing two strings together. Use `.equals()` instead.

Here is an example. Take the first if statement

You have:

```
if ((zone <= 2) && (type == "adult")){
        System.out.println("The fare is 20.");
    }
```

Try:

```
if ((zone <= 2) && (type.equals("adult"))){
        System.out.println("The fare is 20.");
    }
```

This comparison compares the string value. Do this for the rest of your comparisons and you should see the results you want.